# MVC : Linear communication vs. Triangular communication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

In **[WikiPedia (Comparison with the MVC architecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Comparison_with_the_MVC_architecture)**, it is said that - "*MVC architecture is triangular: the view sends updates to the controller, the controller updates the model, and the view gets updated directly from the model*"

Again through **[ASP.Net Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412.aspx)** and the **[image](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC263184.png)**, it is clear that MVC support triangular communication.

But the query is how and when the view interacts with the model OR vice-versa.

It is admirable to get some code to make it clear that, how & when MVC supports triangular communication.

Comment: The view can issue queries the same way the controller does.  MVC really just offers guidelines--they can be broken (or worked around).

Comment: +1 for the comment on "MVC really just offers guidelines"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC, like other design patterns or compound patterns, leaves a lot open to the designers to adapt/adopt/understand in his or her own way.

If you look at the history of MVC, it was invented a good few decades ago out of the Smalltalk language, which bears some differences with our current commonly used OO languages Java, .NET or C++. Hence, there have been many interpretations on how MVC SHOULD work. There isn't the correct solution! It's up to you. Maybe MVC, the way you know it is actually MVP, and not MVC in the other's eyes. I experienced it who know how many times. If you're interested, here are a few discussions about MVC, the differences and how to implement it that I liked.

- [GUI Architechture](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)
- [Build your own Composite Application Block series: UI Architechtures, Patterns and WinForm Examples](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents)
- [MVVM vs MVP vs MVC: The differences](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/mvvm-vs-mvp-vs-mvc-the-differences-explained)

Now the important point to note is that, MVC primarily aims to separate the View from the Model, so that multiple Views can share the same model. So to answer your question concretely: "how and when the view interacts with the model OR vice-versa"

- When: mostly when there is a change in the model, it will automatically send a signal to update all the views.
- How: Either the model encapsulates all information needed to refresh and send it to Views, or Views hold a reference to the model and directly query its state when necessary (or through Controller). As you wish.